# Decrease the size of "light box" image in product view page

Tags: zoom

Please visit this link : http://demo.kidsdial.com/boys-toys/bikes-trikes-ride-ons/toysbox-mind-builder-construction-set-37-models-44-pcs.html

On the bottom right of the image there is "+ with balloon" image, if you click on that the real product image will open.

Is it possible to decrease the size of that image?

What I am saying is that if we download the products list and related products image and all it will download the image with "what size we set in admin panel".

But on the product view page, if we click on "+ with balloon" image, the real product image with the big size will open.

Can we reduce the size of that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [How to fix the width and height of jquery lightbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529460/how-to-fix-the-width-and-height-of-jquery-lightbox) or [jQuery Lightbox Image Size : Limit the max size of Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296810/jquery-lightbox-image-size-limit-the-max-size-of-image)

You could try to set the max width by doing

```
$('#gallery a').lightBox({
  maxHeight: 700, 
  maxWidth: 700
});
```

Please note : this will not change the physical image size and you may want to use magento to resize the image using

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>
```

Comment: hi thanks a lot for reply. can you please tell me in which file, i have to place this . please give me full code. i am new to jquery.....

Answer (score 1):

(I can't comment yet I don't have enough reputation)
You can find the file by searching the files for some content of the page, i.e. you can do a search for "product-img-box" in your files, it should be somewhere in app/design/frontend/default/[yourtheme]/template/catalog maybe in catalog/product/view.phtml?